# JSP/Servlet rewrite URL

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, url-rewriting

I'd like to change the URL of some pages in my website in the same way as foursquare is doing:

from www.foursquare.com/v/anystring/venueid

to www.foursquare.com/v/venue-name/venueid

For example central park in new york:

https://foursquare.com/v/writeherewhatyouwant/412d2800f964a520df0c1fe3

becomes

https://foursquare.com/v/central-park/412d2800f964a520df0c1fe3

I'm developing a pure JSP/Servlet app, no frameworks, in a Tomcat container.

I'm thought of using tuckey's urlrewritefilter, but I don't see how can I use dynamic values coming from the servlet itself there (the venue name)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like you need to use [Restlet](http://restlet.org/) to accomplish this. Check its tutorial: [Routers and hierarchical URIs](http://restlet.org/learn/tutorial/2.1/#part11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here's something you could try:

1) Create a servlet with a servlet-mapping matching the common (prefix) part of the URL (e.g. for foursquare the pattern would be `/v/*`).

2) In your servlet, retrieve the remaining part of the URL path using `request.getPathInfo()`. You can then parse it using regular string utilities and convert it to the new path you'd like.

3) Assuming your updated path is in a variable called `newUrl`, call `response.sendRedirect(newUrl)` to tell the browser to update its URL. This will also call your servlet again with the new path, so it needs to handle both cases.

See the javadoc for `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()` for more info about how it handles relative vs absolute paths, etc.

Comment: thanks, even if it's not as "clean" as I would have loved to, it's a good solution